# R: Create output of the form "text", "text" and not "text , text"

Tags: r

I have this:

```
command.part.1<-c("text1")
command.part.2<-c("text2")
```

And I want this output

```
[1] "text1", "text2"
```

So I can ultimately give this output to my function F

```
F("text1", "text2")
```

Is this possible?

My F takes actually 4 different function arguments (text1, text2, text3, text4) and for each of these file.names I have various possibilities, so I am looping trough these options.
I have all my possibilities for each of the four different arguments stored in a list `command.parts` with a length of 50.

```
for(i in 1:length(command.parts)){
    for(t in 1:4){
    F(command.parts[[i]][1]
      , command.parts[[i]][2]
      , command.parts[[i]][3]
      , command.parts[[i]][4]
      )
}
```

This works, but then I have the F in a loop and I wanted to circumvent this by storing the commands in a container first and feed the pieces of the container to my F.

Comment: what you also have to know is that when you use the backslash to escape a `"`, it still gets printed out but isn't part of the actual string. Check it with `nchar(result)`

Comment: Can't you wrap your function call in another function which will take only one arg ? Well, all in all, what's the goals ? This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/287976)

Answer (score 0):

I would got this way:

```
# example function taking two args
f<-function(a,b) {
  print(paste("a is",a))
  print(paste("b is",b))
}

# wrapper taking noly one arg
fwraper <-function(z) {
  f(z[1],z[2])
}

# call with a vector of values
fwraper(c(command.part.1,command.part.2))
```

but again, it's highly unclear what you're trying to achieve.